# Rewrite Rule to append

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am currently working on a Rewrite Rule where I need to append certain text into the redirected URL.

The URL that  that I want to type into the browser is

```
http://testwebsite.com/search/?q=SEARCH_STRING
```

I want this redirected to

```
http://testwebsite.com/search/SEARCH_STRING/
```

Basically the SEARCH_STRING needs to be taken from infront of ?= and put after /search/

The current rule that I have is malfunctioning:

```
RewriteRule ^.*\/search\/\?q=(.*) /#!/search/$1/ [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: no need to escape forward slashes in an apache regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the query string in a RewriteCond, it's not part of the string your RewriteRule implicitly matches against

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/search/$ /search/%1? [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

The trailing ? deletes the existing query string.